# Can you use the Value of a Combo Box to select a Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ComboBox that has a Value of "ConcretePad". I also have a Range named "ConcretePad". 
i am trying to Select Range based off of ComboBox Value.

```
***Private Sub CatagoryCB_Change()
Dim rg As String
rg = (CatagoryCB.Value)
Worksheets("Data").Select
If (CatagoryCB.Value = "") Then
GoTo Line2
ElseIf (CatagoryCB.Value <> "") Then
Range(rg).Select
Line2:
End If
End Sub***
```

Trying to make rg represent the Value of CatagoryCB.Value, which i did but when i put it in the cell reference for range i get an error

Comment: Tip 1: Don't use `GoTo` unless you're doing error handling. It isn't even needed here - Your `If` and `ElseIf` does what you're trying to do with the `GoTo` already. Get rid of `GoTo Line2` and `Line2:` altogether.

Comment: Secondly, what are the values in your ComboBox? I see that you're trying to select the range using the value. This would work if the values are like `A3` or `B7`. If the values are not cell ranges, you need to figure out what the range of the item you're trying to select is.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for something like this (provided you're using a ListFillRange):

```
Private Sub CatagoryCB_Change()
If (CatagoryCB.ListIndex <> -1) Then
    Worksheets("Data").Select
    Range(CatagoryCB.ListFillRange).Cells(CatagoryCB.ListIndex + 1, 1).Select
End If
End Sub
```

This just grabs the `ListFillRange`, navigates to the `ListIndex` which is in sync with it and selects it.

`CatagoryCB.ListIndex` will return the index of the selected item in the list.

If a value that isn't in the list is selected, it will return `-1`.

So, for example, if I set my `ListFillRange` to `A1:A3` and select the first option, I will do a `Range("A1:A3").Cells(1, 1).Select` because the `ListIndex` of the selected item is `0` (first item) and `.Cells(0 + 1, 1)` = `.Cells(1, 1)`.

If you're populating the ComboBox manually, you'd need to give it the range you want to link to or perform a `find` operation.

It's hard to tell from your code.

[image: ListFillRange]

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My (CatagoryCB.Value) was not equal to my Range Name. This is the code i was able to produce to add a part to my datasheet on my current worksheet. This also adds the new row to my range

```
Dim i As String
Dim c As Integer
Dim g As Integer
i = CatagoryCB.Value
Worksheets("Data").Select

If i = "" Then
GoTo Line2
ElseIf i <> "" Then
Range(i).Select
c = Range(i).Count
Range(i).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(c, 0).Select
g = ActiveCell.Row
Worksheets("Data").Rows(g).Insert
Range(i).Resize(c + 1).Name = i
Cells(g, 1).FormulaR1C1 = Cells(g - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1
Cells(g, 3) = (Part_NumberTB.Value)
Cells(g, 4) = (VendorCB.Value)
Cells(g, 5) = (DescriptionTB.Value)
Cells(g, 7) = (CostTB.Value)
Cells(g, 8) = (CostTB.Value * 1.35)
Cells(g, 9) = (CostTB.Value * 1.35)
Cells(g, 10).FormulaR1C1 = Cells(g - 1, 10).FormulaR1C1
Cells(g, 11).FormulaR1C1 = Cells(g - 1, 11).FormulaR1C1
Line2:
End If
```

Comment: Just wanted to say years later to please not use `Goto` for things like this. It's a terrible practice. Just change your if statement to `If i <> "" Then` rather than using `Goto.`